# Left Column phtml file in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm trying to change the categories in the left column but I don't find the file to modify. This is the name of the div:

```
<div class="col-left sidebar">
<div id="categories_list">
```

Can you help ? Thanks.

EDIT: 
I Find the solution, I search in "page.xml" where i could find one named "left" and file is located "app/design/frontend/default/my_theme/template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml".

Thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: You show css class. Do you want to change the css ? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

locate the `<div class="col-left sidebar">` in the following
for Default path

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml
```

for theme path

```
/app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/page/2columns-left.phtml
```

and put your `categories_list` div here.

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs improvement. It's kind of vague.
But I'll try in anyway. The contents depend on your theme. In the default theme there is no div with that id.
You can turn on [template path hints](http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-turning-on-template-path-hints/) to see the exact template it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

```
Using template path hints you can easily find your template path files.
Login to admin pannel and under
- System -> Configuration
- Change the “Configuration Scope” to “Default Store View” (or whichever store view you want to see template paths on)
- Under Advanced in the left menu click Developer
- Click “Debug” to expand that section
- Change “Template Path Hints”  to "Yes"
- Click Save Configuration
Now to refresh the front-end and see all the locations of the template files so you can easily modify the correct ones.
```